# Viewing multiple dynamic website pages in one page

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, monitoring

I wanted to view multiple website pages in a same window. I wanted to use this for monitoring purpose. Say, I will put a link that displays cpu utilisation and another the batch jobs status. These two links will be dynamic. So finally I will have one single screen that contains multiple links. Please advise.

Comment: you can use iframe. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

Comment: Why negative ? I know that there are iframes for this. I wanted to know if there are any other solutions/plugins readily available. Basic answers wont help.

Answer (score 0):

I will personally use [Iframes](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_iframe.asp) but they are sometimes blocked because of Headers on some websites.

Comment: First of all the multiple pages can be just like an image and you have a small screen so you can just show a small image of the page. You can show images and than show that page on click.